# Wordpress and Dynamic Programming Php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have geography pages for two types of business listings. Each page goes from state, county, city, but I need to have the same geography shared between two types of business.

My two business types are dentist and chiropractors.

I am trying to have a permalink structure like this:

```
xyz.com/dentist/alabama
xyz.com/dentist/alabama/polk-county/
xyz.com/chiropractors/alabama/
xyz.com/chiropractors/alabama/polk-county/
```

I originally was going to load the geography as pages and subpages, but with that method I cannot get the permalink separated by the type chiropractor and dentist.

So now I have created a custom post type one for chiropractor and one for dentist which give me the permalink

`xyz.com/dentist and xyz.com/chiropractor.`

My question is now how to handle my category geography page. I was wondering if in wordpress it is possible to create a shell page such as `xyz.com/dentist/[state]/` and then through php dynamically build a page for each state? So where it shows [state] it will be replaced with the actual state such as alabama, california etc when that specific page is viewed. But the shell page is just 1 page in the database.

If so could someone give me a basic explanation on how to instruct a programmer to do this?

I realize that wordpress is dynamic, but what I am trying to prevent is loading my database with tons of pages for say states, counties, and cities for dentist and chiropractors.

I have over 5000 dentist listing in the database and then loading each state, county and city with its own category page bogs down the db.

I was wondering if I could have one page loaded in wordpress for say states, and then via php behind the scene build a state category page for each state depending on what the user is viewing.

For instance, the text on the state page might say "Find dentist in Alabama" and then the page would list all the dentist loaded in my database that have a state of alabama.

Then for texas the page might say "Find dentist in Texas" and then list all the dentist loaded in the database that have a state of texas.  All of this would be handled through one single page in my wordpress db call state that kind of acts as a shell page.

The shell page would have this text:  "Find dentist in [insert php code to list state user is viewing]".  Then below this text there would be php code to pull all the dentist in the state the user is viewing.  I am tying to instruct my programmer the best way to do this.

Comment: nitpick: wordpress is written in php, and pretty much any wordpress page is by definition "dynamically built".

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure off the top of my head, but you might be able to do this with the custom post type archives. Whenever you create a post in one of your custom post types the necessary archive/category pages should be made, as long as 'has_archive' is set to true in your CPT args. You could have parent page then that only lists state that are in use. At least that was my first thought!

Comment: If you need to instruct a programmer on how to do this, then you need to find yourself a new programmer. That it not your job, that is the programmers job.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use something like '[WP Super Cache'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) in conjunction with the proper structure as you defined above for your categories.

1. dentist

   - alabama

     - polk-county
2. chiropractor

   - alabama

     - polk-county

Making sure that each layer down has the "parent" of the above layer.  This is a bit labor intensive to configure at first but should work for what you're looking for.

You'll end up with a url similar to:

xyz.com/**category**/dentist/alabama/polk-county/

If you want to scratch the **category** portion you can also create Chiropractor and Dentist as custom taxonomies and creating a custom '.php' file for them.  The result of this would be:

- xyz.com/dentist/alabama/polk-county/
- xyz.com/chiropractor/alabama/polk-county/

WP Super Cache will make it so that the page doesn't have to load from scratch every time someone accesses it and should cut back on your server load.

Hope this helps!